# I can print out the string values of what I read, but I am having trouble converting to use their ASCII equivalent

Tags: c, file, ascii

I am trying to read a few lines from a file and store the ASCII value of each character read as I go line by line. My input looks like this:

[image: input]

Here is what my code originally looked like and what it produced:

```
char buf3[256], buf5[256], buf6[256], buf7[256], buf4[256], buf9[256];
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", buf3);
while (!feof(fp)) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s %s", buf4, buf5, buf6, buf7, buf9);
    printf("\n%c %c %c %c %c", *buf4, *buf5, *buf6, *buf7, *buf9);
}
```

[image: result]

I thought printing out %c would give me the ASCII value.
Is there a way to convert these values?

Comment: You need to use `%d` to print out the ASCII value of a character - example: `printf("%d",buf5[0]);` + learn how to access each character of a string.

Comment: `*buf4, *buf5, *buf6, *buf7, *buf` will print the first character in each array. (the `%d` conversion is correct to print the ASCII value -- to convert to decimal value you would subtract `'0'` from the character value) You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: you should copy and paste the input and output here. Putting them in images will prevent people from trying the code

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose your input `011R0` is stored in array `buf` then to print ASCII value of each character, you'll have to access each character and print it as if you are printing an integer:

```
  int i;
  while(buf[i])
   {
       printf("%d\n",buf[i]);
       ++i;
   }
```

By using indices `[i]` one can access each character if the string. Besides that have a look at this: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score -1):

*I thought printing out %c would give me the ASCII value ?* **No**, the format specifier `%c` prints equivalents `char` value, since `buf4`, `buf5`..etc are char array, so when you prints `*buf5` it prints first char of array & if you print `ascii` value of that, you have to subtract it from `48`(ASCII value of 0) if `*buf` contains digits(0 - 9). For e.g

```
printf("%d\n",(*buf4)  - 48);
```

Or

```
printf("%d\n",(*buf4)  - '0');
```

Also for this particular case its wstage of stack memory to declare five char array like `buf3`,`buf4`..`buf9`. you can use just one char array & do the operation. For e.g

```
int index = 0 ;
char buf[20]; /* lets say each word of file are length of 20 char, you can change it */
while (fscanf(fp,"%s",buf) != EOF) {
        while(buf[index] != '\0') {     
                if(buf[index] >= '0' && buf[index] <= '9') { /*or use isdigit() */
                        printf("%d",buf[index] - 48);
                }
                else { /* apart from 0,1,...9 */
                        printf("%d",buf[index]);
                }
                index++;
        }
        printf(" ");
        index = 0;
}
```

Also read why its wrong to use `feof()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Down voter please have a look if any other issues or retract Dv.